# Multiply in MAC-1 assembly language

Tags: assembly

I'm learnign MAC-1 assembly language and i learnd how to adding (ADDD) and how to subtract (SUBD) but i dont know how to multiply and how to use bracket's.

For example:

```
2 * 5 - (6 + 3)
```

I would like to know how to solve that problem.

Comment: Multiplication is done with loops. 15 = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3

Answer (score 0):

For CPUs that do not have a multiplication instruction (such as MAC-1), you can do multiplication by repeated addition.

In assembly language psuedo-code, that could be done with something like:

```
; mult - multiply r1 * r2 (both unsigned), giving r3

:mult  load r3, 0     ; initialise result
       push r2        ; save register we destroy

:loop  cmp  r2, 0     ; loop until r2 is zero
       jeq  :multx
       dec  r2        ; decrement counter
       add  r3, r1    ; add other value to sum
       jmp  :loop     ; the go back and try again

:multx pop  r2        ; recover original value
       ret
```